# What's the difference of Response.Close() and Response.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, response, dispose

From the resource clean-up perspective, why there are `Response.Close()` and `Response.Dispose()` and which one is more comprehensive (call the other one) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where both methods are provided the implementation of `Dispose` should call `Close`. It is a good idea to use the using statement to ensure that `Dispose`and therefore `Close` is called, even if there is an exception.

In other words do this:

```
using (Response response = ...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Not this:

```
Response response = ...;
// ...
response.Close(); // If there is an exception this might never get called!
```

One difference between closing and disposing an object is that when you dispose an object it usually is not possible to use the object any more (attempting to do so may cause an ObjectDisposedException to be thrown), but after calling Close it may be possible to still use the object.

Note that if you are talking about ASP.NET then you shouldn't normally call Close or Dispose on the Response object.

Comment: Another difference is that `Close` should throw exceptions in some cases where `Dispose`  should not.  For example, proper use of a transaction actions may require that every action be explicitly committed or rolled back.  Calling `Close` without doing so should throw an exception, but calling `Dispose` should trigger a silent rollback (since `Dispose` is likely being called because the transaction was disrupted by an exception, and throwing another exception would rather obnoxiously destroy the first).

Answer (score 1):

From the Design Guidelines for Developing Class Library on [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

> Occasionally a domain-specific name is
>   more appropriate than Dispose. For
>   example, a file encapsulation might
>   want to use the method name Close. In
>   this case, implement Dispose privately
>   and create a public Close method that
>   calls Dispose. The following code
>   example illustrates this pattern. You
>   can replace Close with a method name
>   appropriate to your domain. This
>   example requires the System namespace.

```
/ Do not make this method virtual.
// A derived class should not be allowed
// to override this method.
public void Close()
{
   // Call the Dispose method with no parameters.
   Dispose();
}
```

Typically I've seen close whenever the resource can be opened or re-opened, since it gives nice symmetry to the method names.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Close()` closes the socket connection to a client.
`Response.Dispose()` is method which implements IDisposable interface and releases allocated resources.

I think `Response.Close()` is called from `Response.Dispose()` method.

For more detailed information you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)